# How to find a matrix $B'$ to $C$, Given matrix $B'$ to $B$ and $B$ to $C$.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $P$ is the transition matrix from
a basis $B'$ to a basis $B$, and $Q$ is
the transition matrix from $B$ to a
basis $C$, what is the transition
matrix from $B'$ to $C$? What is the
transition matrix from $C$ to $B'$?

I have tried doing row operations on $[P|Q]$ where $P$ gave me the identity matrix and $Q$ gave me the $B'$ to $C$ matrix.
Am I going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_{B'}, x_{B}, x_C$ be the coordinates of some point in the bases $B',B,C$ respectively.

Then we have $x_{B} = P x_{B'}$, $x_C = Q x_{B}$, hence we have $x_{B'} = P^{-1} x_B = P^{-1} Q^{-1} x_C$.

It follows that the required matrix is $P^{-1} Q^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider a matrix in the basis $B'$. $PB'$ would give you the matrix in basis $B$. Likewise, given a matrix in basis $B$, $QB$ would give you that matrix in basis $C$.
Additionally, the transition matrix from $B$ to $B'$ is $P^{-1}$.